# Find which viewController is parent

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have three view controllers that push each other on to the navigation controller.

ViewController1 may push VC2 or VC3
VC2 may push VC3

That means, either VC3 is opened by VC1 or VC2. VC1 is a subclass of UITableViewController and VC2 is a subclass of UIViewController.

Now, in VC3 I want to know if VC1 or VC2 created VC3. How can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could check;

```
[vc3 parentViewController];
```

that returns a `UIViewController`. 
According to what you need, you may do

```
if ([[vc3 parentViewController] isKindOfClass:[VC1 class]]) {
   //has been pushed by VC1
}
else if ([[vc3 parentViewController] isKindOfClass:[VC2 class]]) {
   //has been pushed by VC2
}
```

Comment: Well, I do the check in VC3 so I guess I would write: `[self parentViewController]`, correct? The class of this is not a UIViewController though, it's a UINavigationController. At least that's what this is returning: `[[self parentViewController] class]`

Comment: Yes, you may call `[self parentViewController]`. It's a little tricky, but you should access the array of UIViewControllers in your UINavigationController. Here's a solution:

    `NSArray *array = [[self navigationController] viewControllers];
    NSLog(@"parentViewController:%@",[[array objectAtIndex:([array count] -2)] class]);`